# The example tabulator for angular does not work: unrecognized type library

Tags: tabulator

The following error occurs after installing tabulator with the "`npm install tabulator-tables - save`" command:

```
Error   TS2306  (TS) The file '../ClientApp/node_modules/@types/tabulator-tables/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

The error is reported on the import statement:

```
import {Tabulator} from 'tabulator-tables';
```

I'm trying to use **"tabulator" in an Angular 5.2.5 project created with Visual Studio 2019**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables';   <--  ERROR  !!!!!!

/**
 * This is a wrapper class for the tabulator JS library.
 * For more info see http://tabulator.info
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabulator-table',
  templateUrl: './tabulator-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabulator-table.component.css']
})
export class TabulatorTableComponent implements OnChanges {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

export default Tabulator;

To the top of the @types/tabulator-tables/index.d.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issues with adding types for tabulator, this is because type annotations not being exported, but there is a way to use them.

After installation of types for tabulator (`npm install --save @types/tabulator-tables`), you should open (or create it, if it's not exists) file `index.d.ts` inside directory `src`, and copy following code into it:

```
declare module 'tabulator-tables' {
  export = Tabulator;
}
```

You need to ensure that you have `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` inside `compilerOptions` of file `tsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.app.json` (depends on your project), and `tsconfig.spec.ts` (it needs for unit testing).

*Very important* to unload and start over `ng serve` after editing of tsconfig.

After that all typings should work. Just in case I created simple [Angular example](https://github.com/Karoshee/AngularTypedTabulator), hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers modify the @types/tabulator-tables library, which has been rejecting pull requests for years in the name of compatibility. I found a **less invasive workaround**:

1. Allow TypeScript to get Type definitions in `src/` (or use your own path instead of src everywhere below):

tsconfig.json (as of TS 4.3, but `typeRoots` has existed for years):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["src/@types", "node_modules/@types"], /* src/@types to override tabulator-tables definition. */
  }
}
```

2. Create `src/tabulator-tables.d.ts`, with the same contents that people normally add the top of @types/tabulator-tables/src/index.d.ts:. Not src/@types, and the name must [match [library-name].d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html#testing-your-types) so that the Tabulator class is defined there.

`src/tabulator-tables.d.ts`:

```js
declare module "tabulator-tables" {
  export = Tabulator; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm install --save @types/tabulator-tables`
2. Add a file `tabulator-tables.d.ts` in /src/app

   `declare module "tabulator-tables" { export default Tabulator; }`

*Important* error when use `export = Tabulator;`